# Not able to manage DB using Webadmin in Plesk

Tags: mysql, centos

I have a VPS running on CentOS 5 with Plesk 9.

I've just added a DB and setup WP. Now I need to access DB using phpMyAdmin.
The problem is that phpMyAdmin is not laoding when I click WebAdmin.

I've looked at different guides, like this one:
http://tutorials.ausweb.com.au/web/Tutorials/Plesk-9/Plesk-9---how-to-manage-your-MySQL-database-with-phpMyAdmin/

Looking at Server Components, I can't see phpMyAdmin listed.
Could this mean that phpMyAdmin is not installed?
If so, how do I install phpMyAdmin on CentOs using Plesk?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check:
You have an entry for localhost in the /etc/hosts file (it should be `127.0.0.1    hostnames,including,localhost`)
Check PHPMyAdmin is installed. I think it comes by default in Plesk, but go to either Server or Settings (I can't remember which one), Updates (bottom right), click your current version of Plesk and type in "php" - look for it there. You should be able to install it from there if not.

Comment: It was actually a browser problem. No pop-up window is launched for Opera. Works fine iwth IE or FF.